# Running python script on xampp

Tags: python, xampp

I googled this and tried everything but I could not run my test.py on apache. 
I have updated httpd.conf file to AddHandler .py

#!/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7

print("Hello World!")

When I open this file in browser I am getting this error

Error message: 
End of script output before headers: test.py

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use `Flask` instead? It start a server that you can access via browser.
[Here](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world) you can find an *Hello world* tutorial, or also [here](https://pythonspot.com/flask-web-app-with-python/).

First, you have to install Flask: `pip install Flask`.
Then the server code, saved in a python file, for example your_server.py, has to look like this:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
app.run()
```

You can run the script, then go to http://localhost:5000/ and you'll see the 'Hello World!' message.
Now you can modify the method hello() to do what you need, or create other method/operations.
The tutorial can give you more details, but this is the main concept.